# What's the best way to handle alternate match intents in Dialogflow-CX chatbot when both intents have similar training phrases?

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-cx

In my situation, There is 2 intent which has similar kind of training phrases. During the flow I am getting both the intent in alternate match intent in JSON response.
I want a solution, if there is, this kind of situation I will take the both the intent name from JSON response and prompt the option for user to select one of those option.

Now I am getting both the intent name from the JSON using Dialogflow-CX apis and I am won't able to figure out the next solution.

let me know if required more explanation on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Per the official [docs](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-settings#priority), 'If there is a potential matching conflict between two intents, it is best to improve the training phrases to address the conflict. If you cannot remove the conflict with training phrases, you can use priorities to provide preference to one of the intents.'